# error in Symfony while using salesforce connected app

Tags: community, connected-apps

i am developing an application in `Symfony2` that use `SalesForce` Users to `login`, so i created a connected app in `salesforce` and i get my customer and secret key, but when i want to `login` in my `Symfony2` application i get this error:

```
error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration
```

when in consulted some forums it seems to have a problem with the `Callback url` so i tried many options but it still gives me the same error.

here's my connected App configuration in `Salesforce`:

```
Connected App Name: testApp
Email: my own email
Logo Image URL  : i choosed the default one that salesforce provide
Icon URL    : same as Logo Image URL    
callback url:http://localhost/Annonces/web/app_dev.php/platform/oauth/callback
Selected OAuth Scopes : Full access
```

i've tried before to log with facebook users and it works but with Salesforce it doesn't

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have finally find a solution: in the `connected app` in `salesforce` i set the `callback url` parameter to this : 
 http://localhost/Annonces/web/app_dev.php/login/check-salesforce

so i just added:**/login/check-salesforce**  and it works.